# What will happen after Thread reach all code?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I ask this because I made my program crash when using lots of Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); <--- This is not my main thread.

I want to know does I really need Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); on the last line?

My code:

```
final Runnable iPlusPlus = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                do{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    i++;
                    if(isLiq >= 5){
                       isLiq = true;
                    }
                }while(isLiq = false);
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                    //Thread.currentThread().stop();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //<---I mean last line.
                }
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //<---I mean last line.
}



new Thread(iPlusPlus){
        public void run(){
            iPlusPlus.run();
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need the `interrupt` call as a last line of the `run()` method.
Once a thread finishes its `run()` method it's done. You don't need to `interrupt` it there explicitly as you did.